# ReferenceError: require is not defined MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB database and I'm getting this error

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///Users/admin/mjml/mjml/playground.js:1:21
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:146:23)
    at async Loader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:165:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:68:5)
```

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const uri =
  '------------------------------'
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
client.connect((err) => {
  const collection = client.db('test').collection('devices')
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close()
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use `require()` inside an ESM module (you can see the `Object.loadESM` in the call stack of the error) which tells us it's an ESM module.  You can't use `require()` in that type of module.  Instead, you must use `import`.

So, you probably want:

```
import {MongoClient} from "mongodb";
```